# Change format of y axis in plotly

Tags: r, formatting, plotly, yaxis

I'm trying to format `y axis` numbers' format (in `plotly`) and - after hours of googling - I've decieded to ask here.

I've got a plot like here:

[image]

generated with this code:

```
library("plotly")
library("dplyr")

data.frame(miesiac_label = as.character(as.roman(c(1:12))),
           ile = c(12000, 12100, 11100, 12000, 12000, 11900, 12200, 12100, 6000, 12100, 12100, 12100)) -> dane
dane$miesiac_label <- factor(dane$miesiac_label, levels = dane[["miesiac_label"]])

plot_ly(dane) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~miesiac_label, y = ~ile,
              type = 'bar', marker = list(color = '#99d3df'))
```

My goal is to change `yaxis` formatting from `12k, 10k, 8k, ...` to more "polish one", so `12 tys, 10 tys, 8 tys, ...`. I know how to change it setting `ticktext` and `ticktext`, but I don't want to set values on my own, I prefer to have them more automatic.

I've read about `thickformat` but I didn't find there option, which would change `k` to `tys`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `layout()` gives you what you want. First, you need to divide your `y` by 1000 (maybe there is another way) and then use `ticksuffix` to add `tys`.

```
plot_ly(dane) %>%
add_trace(x = ~miesiac_label, y = ~ile/1000, type = 'bar', marker = list(color = '#99d3df')) %>% 
layout(yaxis = list(ticksuffix= "tys", title = "ile"))
```